# Create unique cell in generated table

Tags: javascript, html, css

the table was refreshing before, now it doesn't.
now, check the new code snippet, and what the main goal i'm trying to achieve (explained in the last comment), i believe this new snippet will help clarify what i'm looking for. 
im sorry for troubling you a lot but really appreciated the help :D

```js
var isCol = 0;
var board = [];
for (r = 0; r < 7; r++) {
  var line = [];
  for (c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
    line.push(RandomGenerator(50, 500));
  }
  board.push(line);
}

function prs(c, r) {
  showTable(c, r);
  isCol = (isCol + 1) % 2;
}

function toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var ret = false;
  switch (isCol) {
    case 0:
      if (row == chosen_row) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      if (col == chosen_col) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
  }

  return ret;
}

function showTable(chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var str = "";
  str += "<table border=1>";
  for (row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
    str += "<tr>";
    for (col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
      str += "<td onclick='prs(" + col + "," + row + ")'";
      if (toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row)) {
        str += " class='grn' ";
      }
      str += ">";
      str += board[row][col];
      str += "</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
  }
  str += "</table>";

  document.getElementById("ff").innerHTML = str;
}

function RandomGenerator(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

showTable(-1);
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
td:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.grn {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="ff"></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `14 cells`? isn't it `7 x 7 = 49` ? and what do you mean by unique? so one of those 49 cells just needs to get a "unique" attribute?

Comment: yes, they are 49 cells, but i meant horizontal and vertical, my bad, thanks for correcting me though, yes, i'm trying to give one cell unique attribute and im unable to get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the point of "clicking" on one of the cells is. So lets keep your code as it is. Only change is the last few lines on how to select/set a unique table cell as unique...

```js
var isCol=0;
var board=[];
for(r=0;r<7;r++){
 var line=[];
 for(c=0;c<7;c++){
  line.push(r);
 }
 board.push(line);
}


function prs(c,r){
 showTable(c,r);
 isCol=(isCol+1)%2;
  getUnique();
}



function toColor(col,row,chosen_col,chosen_row){
var ret=false;
switch(isCol){
 case 0:
  if(row==chosen_row){
   ret=true;
  }
  break;
 case 1:
  if(col==chosen_col){
   ret=true;
  }
  break;
}

return ret;
}

function showTable(chosen_col,chosen_row){
var str="";
str+="<table border=1>";
for(row=0;row<7;row++){
 str+="<tr>";
 for(col=0;col<7;col++){ 
  str+="<td onclick='prs("+col+","+row+")'";
  if(toColor(col,row,chosen_col,chosen_row)){
   str+=" class='grn' ";
  }
  str+=">";
  str+=RandomGenerator(50, 500);
  str+="</td>";
 }
 str+="</tr>";
}
str+="</table>";

 document.getElementById("ff").innerHTML=str;
}



function RandomGenerator(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}



showTable(-1);

/* keep your code as is for now and add the following lines */
var getUnique = function(){
  var tdElements = document.querySelectorAll('#ff td');
  tdElements[
    RandomGenerator(0, tdElements.length)
  ].classList.add('uniqueCell')
};
getUnique();
```

```css
td{
border:2px solid black;
width:10px;
height:10px;
}
td:hover{background-color:lightgreen;}
.grn{
background-color:green;
color:white;
}

.uniqueCell {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<div id='ff'></div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a game called mattix, its board game (https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5799/mattix)  they explain the rules of the game here, I need one cell to have symbol and keep moving between the cells

Comment: so having the unique class cell go wherever i click, it is needed

Comment: @mikotodread updated the answer, that what you are looking for?

Comment: kinda, thats similar to what i'm looking for, my goal is where i click, the unique cell go, not randomly going to other cells once i click anywhere

Comment: so you want to mark the cell you have clicked with "unique" ?

Comment: Yes, lets clarify it better, currently i have 49 cells, and one of them is unique cell, and in the 49 cells, all of them have numbers, however I want the unique cell to have symbol rather than number, lets say our symbol is (S) and our unique cell placed in CELL1, I click on CELL5, my unique cell moves to CELL5, replacing the numbers in CELL5, to (S), and CELL1 loses its (S) and stays empty, Now I click on CELL10, CELL5 loses (S) and it go empty, it doesnt gain back its number, and (S) go to CELL10, repeat just like that