# How to force unique Cell to delete other cells upon clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Run the Code Snippet Please, it'll allow you to understand my question better**

1. As you can see, I have cells with numbers and one Cell with Symbol (S) and red color.
2. If i click on any other cells, my (S)"UniqueCell" will move there.
3. lets say I click on Cell with number 55, My UniqueCell will move there, replacing the 55 with (S), now I click on other cell, lets say cell that have number 320, my UniqueCell moves from cell 55 to cell 320, now my UniqueCell replaced the 320, with it's (S), however cell 55 gained back its numbers.

How i can prevent the cells from gaining back its numbers? how i can make it lose its numbers permanently once i clicked on it?

**note:** I'm trying to make a game where player A pick vertical and player B to pick horizontal, hence the green moving vertical and horizontal every click, if possible, i want each time i click on cell where the green is, if it was Vertical, player gain those points, if it was horizontal, player b gain the points

```js
var isCol = 0;
var board = [];
for (r = 0; r < 7; r++) {
  var line = [];
  for (c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
    line.push(RandomGenerator(50, 500));
  }
  board.push(line);
}

function prs(curr, c, r) {
  showTable(curr, c, r);
  isCol = (isCol + 1) % 2;
}

function toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var ret = false;
  switch (isCol) {
    case 0:
      if (row == chosen_row) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      if (col == chosen_col) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
  }
  return ret;
}

function showTable(c, chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var str = "";
  str += "<table border=1>";
  for (row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
    str += "<tr>";
    for (let col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
      str += "<td onclick='prs(this, " + col + "," + row + ")'";
      if (toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row)) {
        if(c.textContent == board[row][col]){
          str += " class=uniqueCell";
        }
        else str += " class='grn' ";
      }
      str += ">";
      if(c.textContent == board[row][col]){
        str += 'S';
      }
      else str += board[row][col];
      str += "</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
  }
  str += "</table>";

  document.getElementById("ff").innerHTML = str;
}

function RandomGenerator(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

showTable(-1);

var getUnique = function(){
  var tdElements = document.querySelectorAll('#ff td');
  tdElements[
    RandomGenerator(0, tdElements.length)
  ].classList.add('uniqueCell');
  // update the text of the cell using the class
  document.querySelector('.uniqueCell').textContent = 'S';
};
getUnique();
```

```css
td{
  border:2px solid black;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  text-align: center;
}
td:hover{background-color:lightgreen;}
.grn{
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
}

.uniqueCell {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id="ff"></div>
```

Comment: you ask similiar question with similar code over and over again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60363409/create-unique-cell-in-generated-table/60363553#60363553 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60376657/select-a-cell-from-the-table-and-giving-it-unique-class and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60364317/how-i-can-stop-the-table-from-refreshing

Comment: did i break any rules friend? if so i'll delete the post and i apologize :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create unique cell in generated table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60363409/create-unique-cell-in-generated-table)

Comment: it doesn't, unfortunately

Comment: however it helped me understand some things i can do to help me which progressed me a little bit

Comment: what you want to achieve is keeping  Points for each player right

Comment: @Rkv88 - Kanyan, yes and them being displayed

Comment: Your latest edits, especially your last one, made your question worse. Don't deface your question by deleting large chunks of your post, especially when it contains the code you're talking about in the first place. I rolled those edits back to bring your question back to a state where the below answer make sense again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we keep points collected in object P1  & P2  it has for now  points property `P1.points` & `P2.points`

I added inside prs() funtion  called in Onclick

```
  $('#turn').text(`Player ${(isCol+1)} turn`);
  if (CellPoint) {
    if (isCol) {P1.points+=CellPoint;}else{P2.points+= CellPoint;}
    $('#p1').text(`Player 1: ${P1.points}`);
    $('#p2').text(`Player 2: ${P2.points}`);
  } else {
    console.log('selected S');
  }
```

```js
var isCol = 0;
var CellPoint = 0;
var board = [];
var P1 = {
  points: 0
};
var P2 = {
  points: 0
};
for (r = 0; r < 7; r++) {
  var line = [];
  for (c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
    line.push(RandomGenerator(50, 500));
  }
  board.push(line);
}

function prs(curr, c, r) {

  CellPoint = parseInt($(curr).text());

  showTable(curr, c, r);
  isCol = (isCol + 1) % 2;
  clr = isCol ? 'blue' : 'red';
  $(curr).text('S');
  $('#turn').css("color", clr)
    .text(`Player ${(isCol+1)} turn`);
  if (CellPoint) {
    if (isCol) {
      P1.points += CellPoint;
    } else {
      P2.points += CellPoint;
    }
    $('#p1').text(`Player 1: ${P1.points}`);
    $('#p2').text(`Player 2: ${P2.points}`);

  } else {
    console.log('selected S');
  }


}

function toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var ret = false;
  switch (isCol) {
    case 0:
      if (row == chosen_row) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      if (col == chosen_col) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
  }
  return ret;
}

function showTable(c, chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  if(c!==-1){board[chosen_row][chosen_col] = 'S';}
  var str = "";
  str += "<table border=1>";
  for (row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
    str += "<tr>";
    for (let col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
      str += "<td onclick='prs(this, " + col + "," + row + ")'";
      
        if(board[row][col]=='S'){
          str += " class=uniqueCell";
        } else{
        if (toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row)) {
        str += " class='grn' ";} }
     
      str += ">";
      if(board[row][col]=='S') {
        str += 'S';
      } else str += board[row][col];
      str += "</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
  }
  str += "</table>";

  document.getElementById("ff").innerHTML = str;
}

function RandomGenerator(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

showTable(-1);

var getUnique = function() {
  var tdElements = document.querySelectorAll('#ff td');
  tdElements[
    RandomGenerator(0, tdElements.length)
  ].classList.add('uniqueCell');
  // update the text of the cell using the class
  document.querySelector('.uniqueCell').textContent = 'S';
};
getUnique();
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.grn {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.turn1 {
  background-color: green;
  color: red;
}

.turn0 {
  background-color: green;
  color: blue;
}

.uniqueCell {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span id='p1' style='color:red;'>Player1: </span>&nbsp; X &nbsp;<span style='color:blue;' id='p2'>Player2: </span></div>
<p id='turn'>Player 1 turn</p>
<div id="ff"></div>
```

Comment: Kanyan, check my code, i updated it, unfortunately its not working in my code, its not counting each time i click, also i'm receiving these two errors  JSX element 'script' has no corresponding closing tag.javascript and '</' expected.javascript

Comment: wait, i got it to work, but still it cancelled out my other code https://prnt.sc/r7i7ft , now the cell i click on, doesnt get deleted unlike my the code in my snippet, check the thread

Comment: Ah  you also want   to delete the selected ok

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are redrawing the table in each click of cells, as a result keeping track of the previously clicked elements are little bit difficult. Instead create the table only for single (first) time then loop through all the *td*'s to add the style and text based on specific condition.

You can try the following way:

```js
var isCol = 0;
var board = [];
for (r = 0; r < 7; r++) {
  var line = [];
  for (c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
    line.push(RandomGenerator(50, 500));
  }
  board.push(line);
}

function showTable(c, chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var str = "";
  str += "<table border=1>";
  for (row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
    str += "<tr>";
    for (let col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
      str += `<td>${board[row][col]}</td>`;
    }
    str += "</tr>";
  }
  str += "</table>";
  document.getElementById("ff").innerHTML = str; 
}

function RandomGenerator(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

showTable(-1);

var getUnique = function(){
  var tdElements = document.querySelectorAll('#ff td');
  tdElements[
    RandomGenerator(0, tdElements.length)
  ].classList.add('uniqueCell');
  // update the text of the cell using the class
  document.querySelector('.uniqueCell').textContent = 'S';
};
getUnique();

var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
var isPlayerA = true;
var playerA = 0;
var playerB = 0;
tds.forEach(function(td){
  td.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.querySelectorAll('.grn').forEach(td => td.classList.remove('grn'));
    var col = this.cellIndex + 1;
    var row = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
    if(isPlayerA){
      this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(td => td.classList.add('grn'));
      isPlayerA = false;
      playerA += Number(this.textContent);
    }
    else{ 
      document.querySelectorAll(`td:nth-child(${col})`).forEach(c =>c.classList.add('grn'));
      isPlayerA = true;
      playerB += Number(this.textContent);
    }
    this.textContent = 'S';
    this.classList.add('uniqueCell');
    console.clear();
    console.log(`Player A: ${playerA} :: Player B: ${playerB}`);
  });
});
```

```css
td{
  border:2px solid black;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  text-align: center;
}
td:hover{background-color:lightgreen;}
.grn{
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
}

.uniqueCell {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id="ff"></div>
```

Comment: i see, however that wouldn't exactly work  for my end main goal project, Its required to keep track of the cells that is collected from player A and B.

Comment: @mikotodread, I strongly believe that you can easily do that as you have the different text (`S`) for those columns:)

Comment: okay, Let me try to do that, and i'll update you back on any progress or problems

Comment: struggling to understand some parts of the code, but i'm researching and learning, i'm trying to let Player A and B only be able to pick where there is green color background, i tried using `$("#fontWrap").click(function () {
    $("#fontSel")[0].click();
}); `  and for the player A and B to collect numbers, i tried using function to specifically do that, it didn't work,  I'll keep trying @Mamun

Comment: @mikotodread, initially there is no cell with green color, how you are going to allow the first click. Also you didn't use any jQuery in the question but in the comment you have used jQuery! Anyway, best of luck:)

Comment: i added html elements giving color and the id, that doesnt work like that it looks like, i believe i  need to give in javascript the cells of color green instead of using the css, or maybe i can link it, and thank you

Comment: @mikotodread, FYI, redrawing the complete HTML again and again where only a single element's content needs to be updated is simply a bad practice!

Comment: i see, will keep that in mind, have a lot to learn, i hope next semester teacher actually give us enough/info lectures for the projects he's asking for